# WebKit и mail.ru некорректная работа PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, webkit, mail.ru

Всем привет. 
У меня приложение типа QMAinWindow в нем QWebKit.QWebView. Все работает, но например, сайт mail.ru работает некорректно. А иммено, при клике по новостям нет перехода.  Такое же замечаю при клике на некоторые рекламные объявления. LocalStorage подключен и работает. 
С чем это связано и как заставить ВебКит работать нормально?

Вот код

```
import sys 
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWebKit.QWebView()
    window.settings().globalSettings().setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.LocalStorageEnabled, True)
    window.settings().setLocalStoragePath("/home/user/Browser/Storage/")
    window.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://mail.ru"))
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: WebKit имеет, например, ряд багов. Вполне возможно что он некорректно работает...

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код. К примеру, многое зависит от того, как вы обрабатываете открытие страницы в новом окне.

Comment: Код простейший, добавил... Работает некорректно как написано выше...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить обработку клика на ссылки и связать сигнал клика на загрузку кликнутой ссылки:

```py
...
window = QtWebKit.QWebView()
window.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QtWebKit.QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
window.linkClicked.connect(window.load)
...
```

Comment: Спасибо. Т.е. уже средствами самой qt4 влиять на движ ВебКита. Я думал где то настройка в самом ВебКите...

Comment: Другого я не нашел :)